# How do I compare tables of different sizes in sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to compare a smaller table to a larger table. The smaller table is comprised of 3 fields that recur in the larger table. One of the fields is an id. Another is an area measurement. The last is a string. I need to mark the records in the larger table that have values that disagree with values in the smaller table for a given id. The smaller table has at most 60% of the entries of the larger table. I need to account for duplicates.

I've looked around an I haven't found any real discussion on the topic.
I'll be using  sqlite3 for this.

Comment: So you have tables A and B with the same keys, and you want to compare each row where A and B share the same key? Sounds like a simple join to me.

Comment: They have different keys. Small tables keys are a different field in larger table that I need to compare.

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Steve This question is potentially salvageable if you're able to provide a sample of the data with some table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A = small table
B = large table

```
select * from B, A
where A.ID = B.MatchingField
AND (A.Measurement <> B.Measurement
OR A.String <> B.String)
```

Comment: [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net)

It is my understanding that for the basics, all SQL languages are very similar. The site above is a great starting place.